How do I float xml normally with a windowmanager?
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()

    windowManager = getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
    binding = ActivityLockBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(this))
    lockView = binding.root

    val params = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL or
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN or
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT,
    )

    windowManager.addView(lockView, params)
}

I popped up activity_lock.xml with the code above. However, the form of the button I set in activity_lock.xml doesn't apply, and a default button of grey rectangles is created as shown below. Why?

I'm looking forward to the form being applied normally.
